# How to make 404 page ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, http-status-code-404

When i try go to site.ru/gdfgsdf page, it says:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/gfdg"
Rails.root: /site.ru

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes
Routes match in priority from top to bottom
```

But, when i try go to site.ru/404 page, it says my work 404 page.

How to make a 404 page for everyone, if it is not registered in routs?

Comment: Try article https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages

Comment: I already make it. It is not a solve :(

Comment: Post your routes file, please. Does it work in development but not production? Have you restarted your rails server after making changes to your `application.rb` file?

Comment: my routes:       

  match '/404', to: 'errors#not_found', via: :all
  match '/422', to: 'errors#unacceptable', via: :all
  match '/500', to: 'errors#internal_server_error', via: :all

  match '/404', to: 'errors#not_found', via: :all
  match '/422', to: 'errors#unacceptable', via: :all
  match '/500', to: 'errors#internal_server_error', via: :all

Comment: `/404` means nothing to Rails. You can do this by adding a default route to catch all misses like `/*path` or by using `rescue_from` in your ApplicationController.

Comment: Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWGCiHDP-u4&t=228s

Comment: Thank you! Add in routes `get '*unmatched_route', :to => 'errors#not_found'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behavior in dev mode. In development env, the routing errors are displayed so the developer can notice them & fix them.
If you want to see the 404 page, start the server in production mode & check it.

```
$ rails s -e production # script/rails s -e production
```

OR if you don't want to always run the server in prod mode, try doing this in your `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue_404
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :rescue_404

def rescue_404
  #custom behavior
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this very easily such as follow the steps

Step 1: run this below command

```
rails generate controller errors not_found
```

Step 2: open & modify this controller such as below

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def not_found
        render(:status => 404)
    end
end
```

Step 3: update the routes such as below

```
match "/404", to: "errors#not_found", via: :all
```

Step 4: update the configuration file which is `application.rb`

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Step 5: Remove default template from the public folder like 404.html

And Restart your server then test `localhost:3000/404` it will automatically work on `production` server

for details, you can see [this blog post](https://techsolutionshere.com/generate-dynamic-error-page-rails/)